# React + Spring Boot: Can't get Authorization value from Header

Tags: javascript, java, reactjs, spring-boot, axios

I'm trying to create a React app that uses a Spring Boot application as the backend. The user receives a Json Web Token when their login operation is successful in a header param called "Authorization":

```
@Override
protected void successfulAuthentication(HttpServletRequest request, HttpServletResponse response, FilterChain chain,
        Authentication authResult) throws IOException, ServletException {

    String login = ((UserSS) authResult.getPrincipal()).getUsername();
    String token = jwtUtil.generateToken(login);
    response.addHeader("Authorization", "Bearer " + token);
}
```

I used Insomnia to test the endpoint and it seems to work because the token was retrieved as expected:

[image: Insomnia POST request to login endpoint]

The problem is that when using React and Axios the header value is not found:

```
const [login, setLogin] = useState('');
const [password, setpassword] = useState('');

async function handleLogin(e) {
    e.preventDefault();

    const response = await Api.post('/login', {
        login, senha: password
    });

    console.log(response.headers);
    if(response.headers['authorization']){
        history.push("/menu");
    }
}
```

[image: console.log(request.headers) result]

Even though it's inside the XHR, but I can't get it:

[image: Authorization header value inside XHR]

My CORS configuration:

```
@Bean
CorsConfigurationSource corsConfigurationSource() {

    final UrlBasedCorsConfigurationSource source = new UrlBasedCorsConfigurationSource();
    CorsConfiguration config = new CorsConfiguration();
    source.registerCorsConfiguration("/**", config.applyPermitDefaultValues());

    return source;
}
```

Any idea what it could be?

Comment: Is there any particular reason that you are sending JWT in header? Why not send it in response body?

Comment: It's my first time using JWT so I don't know which one is the best way to do it. In this particular case I sent the token in the header because that's the way the course at Udemy taught. What would be the best way?

Comment: Send it in response body. As far as my exposure goes, that's the widely used practice. If you need guidance, this is a good starting point https://github.com/nydiarra/springboot-jwt

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The source of the problem was that I needed to tell CORS to expose the header:

```
@Bean
CorsConfigurationSource corsConfigurationSource() {

    final UrlBasedCorsConfigurationSource source = new UrlBasedCorsConfigurationSource();
    CorsConfiguration config = new CorsConfiguration();
    source.registerCorsConfiguration("/**", config.applyPermitDefaultValues());
    //allow Authorization to be exposed
    config.setExposedHeaders(Arrays.asList("Authorization"));

    return source;
}
```

In my frontend 'Authorization' is retrieved in lower case 'authorization'.